# How is web.xml called ?who calls web.xml

Tags: tomcat, servlets, weblogic

Explanation:
 after we start the server(tomcat/weblogic)?Where the location of the web.xml is mentioned and how the tomact/weblogic server knows from which path to pick the web.xml for our application?

Answer (score 0):

The web.xml is called '[Deployment Descriptor](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=java+deployment+descriptor)'. It tells your server how to configure your app. It has to be placed in [Project_Root]/WEB-INF/web.xml and is automatically loaded at startup of your application. It is defined in the [sevlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).

Comment: when you say it is automatically loaded at startup ,It must have been specified somewhere that from this location(project-root/web-inf) you have to read this file(web.xml)..

Comment: Indeed it is specified.